# GitLab-CI: can't deploy using lftp any more

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, sftp

I have a problem with my deploy script in GitLab CI which used to work for the last two years. Since a week or so, the auto-verification of the root ECDSA is not working (I'm using lftp to deploy some files) .

This is how the output of the pipeline used to looked like.

```
$ lftp -u $FTP_USERNAME,$FTP_PASSWORD -p 22 sftp://my.ftp.server -e "debug; set sftp:auto-confirm yes; mirror --reverse --verbose --delete public/ mount/; bye"
---- Running connect program (ssh -a -x -s -l ftp_products -p 22 my.ftp.server sftp)
---> sending a packet, length=5, type=1(INIT), id=0
<--- The authenticity of host 'my.ftp.server (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)' can't be established.
<--- ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:Z2s4NdXMJ04EfN3jm4xZ/ZwJE4E6Lj/HP8oHWzIod4M.
<--- Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
```

Note that ssh asks for confirmation whether or not to continue, which is confirmed with `yes` by the command line option `sftp:auto-confirm yes`. The pipeline continues as intended.

Since last week, I get this as output from my deploy script:

```
$ lftp -u $FTP_USERNAME,$FTP_PASSWORD -p 22 sftp://my.ftp.server -e "debug; set sftp:auto-confirm yes; mirror --reverse --verbose --delete public/ mount/; bye"
---- Running connect program (ssh -a -x -s -l ftp_products -p 22 my.ftp.server sftp)
---> sending a packet, length=5, type=1(INIT), id=0
The authenticity of host 'my.ftp.server (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)' can't be established.
<--- ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:Z2s4NdXMJ04EfN3jm4xZ/ZwJE4E6Lj/HP8oHWzIod4M.
**** Timeout - reconnecting
---- Disconnecting
---- Running connect program (ssh -a -x -s -l ftp_products -p 22 my.ftp.server sftp)
---> sending a packet, length=5, type=1(INIT), id=0
The authenticity of host 'my.ftp.server (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)' can't be established.
<--- ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:Z2s4NdXMJ04EfN3jm4xZ/ZwJE4E6Lj/HP8oHWzIod4M.
**** Timeout - reconnecting
---- Disconnecting
```

Note, that ssh isn't even prompting for `yes|no`, so the command-line option to confirm the fingerprint automatically has no effect.

Has anyone faced this problem before and has a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I started experiencing the same issue while using `node` docker image in my GitLab CI, which uses Debian under the hood. I was just using `node` meaning that in fact it was `node:latest`, that would most likely use the newest Debian version.

I found the following [bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=964953) on Debian website mentioning that there is a problem with `lftp` and Debian Bullseye version, where that SSH prompt is in fact not displaying. Debian Buster worked just fine.

I switched the image to `node:bullseye` and this problem persisted. Then I changed the image to the older `node:buster` and the problem was gone.

I would suggest investigating your image to determine what OS is it based on. If that is Debian as well, try playing around with versions. Hopefully that will get fixed soon.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to this [bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=964953) in Debian Bullseye then one workaround is to set this in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` or `~/.ssh/config`:

```
StrictHostKeyChecking accept-new
```

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the man page of [`lftp`](https://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html) and found the option `sftp:connect-program`:

> the program to use for connecting to remote server. It should support `-l' option  for user  name,` -p' for port number. Default is `ssh -a -x'.  For private key authenticaвЂђ tion add` -i' option with the key file.

Instead of this:

```
lftp -c "set sftp:auto-confirm yes; open ...
```

We could use this:

```
lftp -c "set sftp:connect-program 'ssh -a -x -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'; open
```